# Shift+1 is bound to Windows Explorer regardless of what program I am using

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, hotkeys

Shift+1 is permanently bound to C:\Windows\explorer.exe. Even when I try to play any video games, or use any other programs, the priority for this hotkey is assigned to explorer.exe. Meaning that I am unable to use the Shift+1 hotkey in anything at all. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode, what happens? If you use AutoRuns to insure that no necessary applications required to boot your machine are loaded, what happens?

Comment: It's not on my machine, so it's a program running on your pc that's doing it.  Interestingly **win+1** opens the first pinned item on the taskbar.  **2** opens the second and so on.

Comment: Are you talking about key combo 'Shift'+'1' or 'Shift'+'F1'? 'Shift' can be used in a hotkey combo only with the function keys, as with regular keys it's reserved for normal usage - for example 'Shift'+'1' produces an exclamation mark (!). Please edit your answer so that it refers to the actual key combo you have problems with.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I will try to explain it better. I have this software running in administrator: https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective. I have World of Warcraft running as well. When I try to use the keybind Shift+1, it is not detected in the game. I cannot use Shift+1 in the game chat to type "!", or to bind it in-game. The output of the program I linked above says that Shift+1 has the process path of C:\Windows\explorer.exe. If I use any other keybind like Shift+2, the program doesn't output anything (meaning it is being used inside the WoW, not by anything else).

Comment: Repeating myself: please edit your question. You do that by clicking "Edit" under the text. That allows you to put the information into the question itself to clarify and focus what you actually are talking about, so people participating in the community don't have to read through comment sections to learn the details of your issue.